# Conditions for logarithmic upper bound on size of antichains in a partial order

Tags: reference-request, order-theory

Suppose I have a partial order $(P,\le)$ (in practice I have a very specific one, but let's start with a generic question).

Are there known conditions that would imply that the size of any antichain is bounded above by $\log(|P|)$?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. Maybe Dilworth's theorem is useful for you, though?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem

Comment: It's very generic, yes, because I'm looking for proof strategies for this bound I'm trying to get on a specific partial order that I cannot define in a question. Dilworth's theorem just gives a different perspective on the definition of the problem but I'm looking for some existing non-trivial results on the size of the antichain.

Comment: Without more information about the structure of your poset it is very hard to say anything useful. Do you know that your poset is Sperner? That would obviously help a lot.

Comment: Thanks @SamHopkins. I don't know if it is Sperner. I'm not familiar with this notion, how would it help? I'm looking exactly for these kind of properties that would help characterizing the size of anti chains in my poset. Unfortunately I cannot define the poset precisely in the question because it would be too specific.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_property_of_a_partially_ordered_set. It is related to Sperner's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem), which basically says that the rank $n$ Boolean lattice is Sperner. See also the LYM inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality).